# How to avoid multiple installation for j2me based application on different mobiles?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, installation

I developed j2me based application. I want to prevent this application for multiple installation on different mobiles. How its possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're distributing the jar directly to consumers for them to load on to their devices themselves, and you want to stop them forwarding it to their friends/putting it on the Pirate Bay?

I'd suggest having them connect to some server to "activate" your app, and have some way of ensuring you can only do it once, maybe a registration code that only works once?

Bear in mind that if your users are paying for your app, they may be disappointed if they can't run it on a new handset if they ever upgrade/have their old one stolen etc.